# What is a Micom chip?

Tags: bios, updates

I downloaded a BIOS updated for my Samsung netbook, and noticed it also updated the MICOM chip. What is a MICOM chip for? I tried Googling it to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone asked the same question in German on another site, so I translated a few things. Turns out MICOM controls an [Embedded System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_system). In this case, it controls the keyboard.

> Unlike previous Samsung models the V20/5 Micom keyboard controller is
>   built into the executable BIOS file to ensure that the correct Micom
>   is used with each new BIOS release. To update the Micom, please see
>   BIOS Updates. ([Samsung WWW site](http://www.samsungpc.com/products/v20/v20_micom/v20_micom.htm))

This means that the controller for your keyboard is automatically updated with the BIOS, so that there are no conflicts.